# Create Extended Navigation Bar on Hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to replicate a Navigation Bar to match this website's: http://sincerelyjules.com/

What I'm trying to do is when hovering over the Navigation Block, it would expand to show Menu Items (check out the website above for an example).

I've used Bootstrap and CSS but neither are working. If anyone could provide some suggestions or material, that would be greatly appreciated! Apologies for the incredibly sloppy coding.

Code below:

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
 body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.nav-bar-block {
  padding: 9px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  background-size: cover;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  display: block;
}
.nav-bar-block h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #4b4b4b;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding: 0px 200px;
}
.nav-bar-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <!-- css -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="nav-bar-block">
      <h1>Navbar Title</h1>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create something like this by using set heights for the navigation bar and CSS transitions.....

```css
body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;       
}


 .nav-bar-block {
   padding: 9px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #F8F8F8;
   background-size: cover;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
   display: block;
   height: 100px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.nav-bar-block:hover {
  height: 160px; 
  transition: all 1s ease;
  }

.nav-bar-block h1 {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
      color: #4b4b4b;
      font-size: 60px;
      padding: 0px 50px;
      margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
}

.nav-bar-menu {
        list-style-type: none;
      margin: 20px auto;
}

.nav-bar-menu li { 
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<nav class="navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="nav-bar-block">
            <h1>Navbar Title</h1>
          <ul class="nav-bar-menu">
            <li>Nav item</li>
            <li>Nav item</li>
            <li>Nav item</li>
            <li>Nav item</li>
            <li>Nav item</li>
            <li>Nav item</li>
            <li>Nav item</li>
           </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

<sub>I'm not a bootstrap user so I don't know bootstrap specific classes</sub>

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it. However, it's not centered when I've added it to my homepage. Currently, the display: inline-block; but this doesn't center the elements. Also, I've added a hover effect on each "Nav Item" to increase font size upon hover. However, upon hovering on each "Nav Item", the elements increase size and push the other Nav Items out of their position. Is there a way to somehow "fix" the position of the Nav Items so when hovering on each item it doesn't disrupt the flow of the Navigation?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Everything you *want* to do is possible, but I can't feasibly build your site for you in comments.